# how to uninstall app that **does not** appear in applications?

Tags: macos

At some point, I installed some application (specifically *"vodafone mobile broadband"*). The application appears in the startup menu (*users & groups -> login items*), but it does not appear in the applications menu. How do I find and remove it??

Comment: I have read that it is very hard to remove this software especially the 'Age-restricted' bar, if it is there, you have must contact them through support. Here one page I have found about the bar, if you have any problem with that...  https://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/Mobile-Broadband/Age-restricted-content-bar-can-not-be-removed/m-p/2640425  There is also a forum there which might help furthering your search. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

## Removal Instructions To remove the Vodafone Mobile Broadband application:

1. Open Applications/Vodafone Utilities
2. Double-click ‘VMB Uninstaller’
3. Select ‘Remove application only’ to uninstall the application but
   retain your settings and data (eg. SMS messages). Or, alternatively,
   select ‘Remove everything’ to uninstall the application and delete
   your settings and data Confirm your selection by clicking ‘Yes’
4. Enter your Administrator password to allow the Uninstaller to run

[SOURCE](http://servizinformatici.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/VMB_for_Mac_4_10_04_00_ReadMe.pdf)

If this does not work there is a handy app called [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to fully uninstall an app, along with all its extra files. Just launch AppCleaner, search for an application in its main window, and click on it, then click the “Remove” button in the popup window that appears:

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).